# Some error in IE about the integration of ZK and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, zk

everyone,
I have faced one problem:

The ZUL code:

```
<window title="Hello World!!" id="winMain" border="none" width="100%" height="100%">

<script type="text/javascript"> 
<![CDATA[
function testAlert() { 
window.open ("http://cn.bing.com", "Show", "menubar=0,resizable=1,location=0,width=683,height=384");} 
]]>
</script>

<div align="center">
<button id="btnShow" label="Show">
<attribute name="onClick">
    <![CDATA[ 
        Clients.evalJavaScript("testAlert()");
    ]]>
</attribute>
</button>
</div>
</window>
```

Function of the ZUL code is opening one new window in some browsers and it works well in CHROME, Firfox. But when I run it in IE8 , some error would arise :

**client error: Failed to process script; 
Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101. (Error)**

Is there some solution for this problem? Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Executions.getCurrent().sendRedirect(string, string)` [javadocs](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Execution.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to do this on server side. But for such a simple requirement you shouldn't need to go to server. Using ZK's [client namespace](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Reference/ZUML/Namespaces/Client) you can call your testAlert() function on button onClick event on the client-side. Both approaches are shown in below code and it works on IE 8 (Standards mode)

```
<window title="Hello World!!" id="winMain" border="none" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns:w="client">

<script type="text/javascript"> 
<![CDATA[
function testAlert() { 
window.open ("http://cn.bing.com", "Show", "menubar=0,resizable=1,location=0,width=683,height=384");} 
]]>
</script>

<div align="center">
<button id="btnShow" label="Show 1">
<attribute name="onClick">
    <![CDATA[ 
        Executions.getCurrent().sendRedirect("http://cn.bing.com", "_blank");
    ]]>
</attribute>
</button>
<button id="btnShow2" label="Show 2" w:onClick="testAlert();">

</button>
</div>
</window>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have try your methods in IE8, 'Execution.getCurrent...' is OK, but it cannot control the size of window popping. The second method 'w:onClick="testAlert();"' would Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "w" for attribute "w:onClick" associated with an element type "button" is not bound.

Comment: I have try again, you are right !!! Last time , I just forgot the xmlns:w="client". Thank you very much!